# Vimeo video autoplay doesn't work in google chrome.

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iframe, vimeo

I have created an *iframe* to play a a video from vimeo.

I am passing autoplay option as an argument with video url. 
It is working fine in firefox. But it is not working in google chrome. Any solution?

```
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/76418753?autoplay=1'></iframe>
```

Even this url also isn't loading in google chrome. But works in firefox.

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/76418753?autoplay=1
```

Comment: This is working perfectly in Google Chrome, Firefox and even Internet Explorer on my computer. Are you sure there are no other problems (in the code, with your plugins, ...)?

Comment: @efux haha _even internet explorer_

Answer (score 3):

[This google products thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/89S0yAGAIAs) says to clear your chrome history and cache and then end all chrome processes in your task manager.  if you can't load the video after that, uninstall chrome and reinstall.  It could also potentially be one of your extensions.